# Detect if a website is restricting navigating their site until you accept alert or popup - using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to detect using python selenium webdriver if a website is restricting viewing or navigating their site until you accept an alert or pop up?

This won't be one URL it will be many implemented in various ways.

If not is there a way to accept the pop up or alert?

Comment: Without looking at the implementation of all of the sites you are talking about and trying to find a common thread, not likely. If you can't detect that a popup is there, I'm not sure how you would accept it.

Comment: one hard way is using accept_alert in all pages in a try-except block, which I don't recommend though.

Comment: @NaveenKumarRB why would you not recommend that?

Comment: you need to add try-except in all places wherever you are navigating a website. if it is a single place to add, then go ahead. Also, I assume accet_alert won't wait for the alert to be preset (implicit wait), so no time killing there for each navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably monitor the window_handles.  So if you are on a page and you can't find the element you want and you think that is because they are blocking you with an alert you can see if the number of window_handles increased, switch to the latest window_handle and deal with it.

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

and you may end up using:

```
driver.switch_to.alert
```

which has a bunch of methods you can use.